# iTextsharp 7 License Key

Tags: itext, itext7

I am trying to use iText in C#. I have everything working perfectly in my code, until I try to add the license key. Everywhere I have looked say to download: itext.licensekey.dll and itext.licensekey.xml. I have done that and added both to my project. I have looked through the xml's 450 lines of code and cannot find where I am supposed to put my key. I got the key from another program that we are using in another part of the company(not C#). Does anyone know what line in the xml file I am supposed to add my key?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The entire xml file *is* the license key. You load it like this:

```
LicenseKey.LoadLicenseFile("path/to/itextkey.xml");
```

as can be read in the license key FAQ: http://developers.itextpdf.com/content/license-key-frequently-asked-questions/how-do-i-load-license-key

Additionally, you have a license key, which means you are a customer with a support contract. You don't need to use Stack Overflow, you can contact iText Software directly. This is particularly relevant for questions regarding license keys, because they are individual to you and questions regarding them are unlikely to benefit other Stack Overflow users.

Additionally, having an official license key for one application doesn't necessarily mean you are allowed to use that same license key for another application (depending on your contract with iText Software). Contact sales for more information.

Additionally, there is no such thing as iTextSharp 7. See this answer for details: [iTextSharp - where are PdfDocument, PdfCanvas, ...?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46089983/itextsharp-where-are-pdfdocument-pdfcanvas/46090668#46090668)

Comment: Additionally: having an official license key for one application doesn't necessarily mean you are allowed to use that same license key for another application (depending on your contract with iText Software).

Comment: This is pretty much what I thought, but based on there "how to" it seemed like it was supposed to be as easy as, setup the file, add key, done. Which is how it works for the other application. Thanks for the fast response.

Comment: _ there "how to"_, what exactly do you mean? The link in the answer above? Or do you have other documentation? If you have downloaded documentation in the past then maybe it is out of date. If you have recently obtained documentation and it's incorrect or incomplete, then please let me know so we can correct this.

Comment: @AmedeeVanGasse sorry I did not respond sooner and now it has been far to long. The problem I believe was I needed a new key for the different server, but that was quiet some time ago and I think it was more of a novice mistake.