# iTextSharp - where are PdfDocument, PdfCanvas, ...?

Tags: vb.net, pdf, itext, itext7

I'm generating PDF documents using iText(Sharp). 
I'm developing the app using Visual Studio 2017.
I've added iTestSharp using NuGet and I've experimented with both VB and C#

All is fine for the 'high-level' stuff (chapter 1 from the jumpstart tutorial). Now I want to go more low-level using 'page', 'canvas' and 'low-level' drawing commands : chapter 2 from the jumpstart tutorial

http://developers.itextpdf.com/content/itext-7-jump-start-tutorial/chapter-2-adding-low-level-content

**My problem is that I can't access the classes PdfDocument, PdfCanvas, etc. these classes are not available..**
Also I can't create a New PdfWriter object (New operator is not implemented)

What's wrong ?

- am I missing some Imports / using libraries ? (I currently include
  iTextSharp.text and iTextSharp.text.pdf)
- has this someting to do with iText V5 - > V7 and is the tutorial maybe a bit out of date ?
- are these classes only available in the Java libraries, and not in the .NET port ?

Does anyone have an example of drawing stuff on a canvas using VB.NET - this would be very helpful!

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To clarify further:

- **iText 5 .NET** is nicknamed **iTextSharp** because of historical reasons that are beyond the scope of a Stack Overflow question.
- **iText 7 .NET** doesn't have a nickname because we (iText Software) want to emphasize that it is exactly the same product as **iText 7 Java**, just for a different platform.

The tutorial you found is not out of date, on the contrary, it's the most recent one. It's the iTextSharp you got from NuGet that is out of date.

If you read the description on NuGet.org then you will clearly see that iTextSharp is the old version: https://www.nuget.org/packages/iTextSharp

> We have two currently supported versions: iText 5 and iText 7. Both
>   are available under AGPL and Commercial license.
>
> - iText 5 AGPL
> - iText 7 community: https://www.nuget.org/packages/itext7/
>
> iText 5 is a one solution library that is complex, but well documented
>   to help you create your solutions.
>
> iText 7 is a complete re-write of iText 5, allowing you to choose your
>   adventure with add-ons, all based on a simple, modular code structure
>   that is easy to use and well documented.

and

> iTextSharp is the .NET port of iText 5.

If this wasn't clear enough for you (and it obviously wasn't), then I would really, *really* appreciate your feedback on how we can improve the description on NuGet.org.

Comment: Thanks Amedee - indeed the iTextSharp package from NuGet was out of date, and this was easily fixed. This is how I ended up with this older version : In 'Manage NuGet Packages' I simply searched for 'pdf'. The iTextSharp V5.5.12 was the top search result (2M downloads), so I assumed it was the best choice.  Searching for 'iText' resulted in itext7 to show up in third position. Thanks for the clarification!

Comment: This is something that we cannot fix easily. iText 5 has been on NuGet since 2011, while iText 7 is on NuGet since 2016, so it would make sense that iText 5 has more downloads than iText 7. And I am not going to set up a bot to artificially boost the download stats of iText 7. The only way we can get the number up for iText 7, is by people like you using it.

Comment: In fact I should have read the section on 'Installing iText7' more carefully, all the answers are there... Instead I was lazy and skipped to the NuGet Package Manager...

Comment: Let's hope that your question helps future careless readers. :)

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have the right NuGet packages on your system.
To try this out, create an empty project and include NuGet packages

- iText7 by iText Software v 7.0.4

The jumpstart tutorial  was written for iText7, so it make sense you'd need that specific version. iText7 is a complete re-write of iText5. So you might indeed find several classes missing if you try to run the samples against the iText5 library.